# magento with maxshop theme create account not working also socialmedia register not showen

Tags: magento

i have some problems with magento and i wish to have some help but I'm not expert with magento just start using it few days ago

create account is not working and i don't know why after search i found the log file include errors check below 
system.log

```
Notice: Undefined variable: block  in \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template\Filter.php on line 197
```

and about the exception.log

```
    2015-11-14T17:34:47+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Not correct (block): Mage_Blog_Block_Blog' in \app\Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('\xD8\xBA\xD9\x8A\xD8\xB1 \xD8\xB5\xD8\xAD\xD9\x8A\xD8\xAD...')
#1 \app\code\local\Ced\CsMarketplace\Model\Layout.php(41): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('blog/blog', Array)
#2 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Layout->createBlock('blog/blog', 'latest-blog')
#3 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('blog/blog', 'latest-blog')
#4 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 \app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 \app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 \app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 \app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 \index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

and social media login not shown in website at all

I'm using this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cedcommerce-social-login.html